# joomla virtuemart adding new category code location

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

This is regarding virtuemart 2.0.
    A new row is inserted into the prefix_virtuemart_categories table when a new category is added. where is this query executed?.i.e,in which file(models/controllers...)  . I want to do something after a new category is added .Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by going to the your `com_virtuemart` component.Here's the navigation from where you category will save it to the database.

> Joomla site -> administrator -> components -> com_virtuemart
>   ->controllers ->category.php

Open this file and you can see there is one function called `save()` ,that is what you want .You can do what else you want here.Good luck.